# Using Redemption RDOContactItem cannot save more than a number of contacts MAPI_E_TOO_BIG

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

found I'm trying to create contacts into a user's Mailbox programmatically (using Redemption), based on values from a database.

```
RDOContactItem rci = (RDOContactItem)session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Folders["Contacts Subfolder"].Items.Add("IPM.Contact");
...
rci.Save();
```

As soon as I reach the limit 250, I get the error:

```
Error in IMsgStore::OpenEntry(Inbox or Root): MAPI_E_TOO_BIG
ulVersion: 0
Error: Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are composing.
Component: Microsoft Exchange Information Store
```

Read Dmitry Streblechenko's comments on "This is an indication that you have too many open objects. Do you open each and every message in a folder?" suggestions on http://www.microsoft-questions.com/microsoft/Plaform-SDK-Mapi/32731171/mapietoobig.aspx and even tried his suggestion "Do you release all Exchange objects as soon as you are done with them?"

```
if (rci != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rci);
```

even casting to IDisposable to able to dispose it, but it didn't work.

I haven't find a way to close a contact item after being saved.

Increasing the number of items that can be opened simultaneously on the server side is not a happy option either.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using multiple dot notation (5 if I am counting correctly), and that causes the compiler to create implicit variables that you cannot explicitly release. Try the following. You can also try to call `GC.Collect()` every once in a while, but that would be a sledgehammer of a solution...

```
RDOFolder contacts = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
RDOFolders folders = contacts.Folders;
RDOFolder subfolder = folders["Contacts Subfolder"];
RDOItems items = subfolder.Items;
RDOMail msg = items.Add("IPM.Contact");
RDOContactItem rci = (RDOContactItem)msg;
...
rci.Save();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rci);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msg);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(subfolder);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contacts);
```

Comment: WOW, it's a great honor to receive the perfect solution from the Redemption's creator. Thank you, Mr. Streblechenko!